# Como usar ajax para fazer select where

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, materialize

Preciso trazer informações do banco para um *modal*, quando eu clicar no botão deve abrir o modal e trazer as `infos`, a `id` do registo pode ser escrita em uma `tag` ou de alguma outra forma?

Mas basicamente é isso preciso trazer informações de cada registo quando clicar no botão deve ser exibido o *modal* e populado com as informações do banco.

Comment: Inicialmente você deve ter uma URL que forneça estas informações. Então, no evento de abrir o modal, você faz a requisição. http://jquerybrasil.org/ajax-com-jquery-metodo-ajax/

Comment: como eu posso passar uma variavel do php ou que esteja em uma taga para o ajax

Comment: por GET, assim:  meu_site.php?minha_variavel=valor

Comment: Ou por POST. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estou no exato momento fazendo um código semelhante

Como vc nunca viu ajax antes farei um feijão com arroz de ajax comentado:

**PAGINA AJAX:**

```
// Coloque um evento para um grupo de elementos que você precisa clicar
$('.seuelemento').click(function(){
    // Ao carregar a pagina voce vai precisar colocar a id em algum lugar no seu html
    // Eu gosto de colocar a id dos elementos no atributo alt, mas pode ser id, title, etc.
    // basta usar a função abaixo pra recuperar a informação do elemento que for clicado
    var id = $(this).attr('alt');
    // Vamos formatar o dado para ser uma requisiçao do tipo GET
    var dados = 'id='+id;
    // Crie uma página pra processar a requisição em segundo plano
    var caminho = "projeto/pagina-de-resposta.php";

   // O nosso ajax vai fazer uma requisição get na sua pagina
   $.get({
      url:caminho,
      data: dados,
      success: function(retorno){
          //metodo executado se for enviado com sucesso
          //O callback retorno receberá tudo que for impresso na sua pagina php
          //Essa função na realidade nao precisa, mas eu gosto de usar pra garantir que vai funcionar.
          var obj = JSON.parse(retorno);
         //Agora basta usar o seu array ou objeto como um JSON para popular o que você quiser na sua página
         $('.elemento').html(obj.nome);
         $('.elemento').html(obj.telefone);
         $('.elemento').html(obj.endereco);

         //Caso a sua requisição esteja retornando um array de objetos, ou array de arrays use a função abaixo para navegar pelos resultados
         $(obj).each(function(key,value){
              $('.elemento').html(value.nome);
              $('.elemento').html(value.telefone);
              $('.elemento').html(value.endereco);
         }
      }
   });
});
```

**PAGINA PHP**

```
//Recebendo os dados da requisição 
$id = (isset($_GET['id']))?$_GET['id']:false;

//Basta agora usar a id para fazer a busca no banco
$resposta = seuMetodoPraBuscarNoBanco($id);

// Convertendo o array ou objeto em JSON
$resposta = json_encode($resposta).

// Devolvendo a resposta pro Ajax
print_r($resposta);
```