# Submeter formulário em janela modal bootstrap, e atualizar a janela com a informação submetida

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia!
galera, minha dificuldade é a seguinte: Tenho uma janela modal, onde carrego uma lista vinda do banco, exibo pra o usuário, e tem um campo onde ocorre uma edição, onde criei um form, e de lá dou o update no meu banco. A edição funciona perfeitamente, meu único problema no momento é, assim que a informação for atualizada no banco, queria que a página desse o refresh na pagina e já abrisse o modal no qual a edição é feita. Não posto código pois não fiz nada relacionado por falta de conteúdo ou conhecimento no assunto.
Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: Bom, assim fica um pouco difícil, mas vamos lá. Esse formulário esta estático na página ou é dinâmico ? Exemplo, tenho uma lista e cada linha da lista as informações na modal mudam.

Comment: Quando for feito o refresh, você poderia criar uma flag e jogar em um input hidden, em seguida, capture esse valor com javascrip. Quando o DOM estiver pronto, você verifica se essa flag esta TRUE. Se sim, abra o modal. Se não, não faça nada.

Comment: Se estiver usando javascript  ou Jquery, adicione as TAG, pois a solução que vou dar é pelo client server.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que a sua página faz refresh, nesse caso basta que o arquivo php que processa o formulário retorne um parametro pra página.

Você pode fazer de duas maneiras: Via `$_GET` ou Via `$_SESSION`

- VIA $_GET :

Basta passar o paramentro via URL:

**Página que processa o formulário:**

```
if ($atualiza == true){
    header('location:pagina.php?sucesso=1');
}
```

**Página da modal**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade <?=((isset($_GET['sucesso']))?'visivel':'')?>" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">...</div>
      <div class="modal-body">...</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- VIA $_SESSION:

Basta criar uma varivel de mensagem e seta-la:

```
if ($atualiza == true){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sucesso'] = 1;
}
```

Página da modal:

```
<?php session_start();?>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade <?=((isset($_SESSION['sucesso']))?'visivel':'')?>" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">...</div>
          <div class="modal-body">...</div>
          <div class="modal-footer">...</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<!--Se a página não trabalha com sessões, você pode destruir a sessão após exibir a mensagem-->
<?php session_destroy();?>
<!--Se a página usa sessão pra outras coisas, ou se no fluxo da aplicação tem outros momentos que a sessão será utilizada após passar por essa página, nesse caso basta limpar o campo da mensagem-->
<?php unset($_SESSION['sucesso']);?>
```

por fim basta que o seu css exiba a modal quando a classe `.visivel` for setada:

```
.visivel{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi, você quer após a atualização no banco a página dê refresh abrindo a modal e mostrando pro usuário a página exatamente no mesmo estado que ela se encontrava antes do envio do formulário. Nesse caso não seria mais intuitivo realizar esse operação sem refresh?

Comment: E como efetuo essa operação sem uso do refresh Adriano?

Comment: @JoséAllison você pode usar o ajax. Pode ser pelo procedimento xmlhttp request do javascript ou pelo $.ajax do jquery (Extremamente simples, eu recomendo). Aqui eu tenho um exemplo de ajax com query, dê uma olhada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125686/como-usar-ajax-para-fazer-select-where/125745#125745